# Replace semicolon between letters in PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have the following issue, I need to replace all semicolons inside a string which appear only between letters with a slash. The issues is that I also have html entities with semicolons and str_replace messes them up.

Sample string:

```
Category A &gt; Subcategory A;Category A &gt; Subcategory B;Category B &gt; Subcategory C
```

Desired output:

```
Category A &gt; Subcategory A/Category A &gt; Subcategory B/Category B &gt; Subcategory C
```

Comment: HTML-decode the string before performing the replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace semicolon between letter only, you can use regex lookahead and lookbehind.

```
$str = "Category A &gt; Subcategory A;Category A &gt; Subcategory B;Category B &gt; Subcategory C";
$str = preg_replace("/(?<!\s);(?!\s)/", "/", $str);
echo $str;
```

or if your html entities is only `&gt;` then you could use code below

```
$str = "Category A &gt; Subcategory A;Category A &gt; Subcategory B;Category B &gt; Subcategory C";
$str = preg_replace("/(?<!\&gt);/", "/", $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I am forever in your debt

Answer (score 0):

You could try str_replace - [http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php], something like:

```
$a = str_replace(";Cat", "/Cat", $a);
```